# How to map array object from firestore database using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

[image: database image]

It drives me crazy it's been 15 days and I'm still trying to figure it out actually, I am working with excel data so I convert the excel data into JSON and then upload it to the database. Please, help me - any help will be appreciated.

This my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import "../CRM.css"
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
import { filedata } from '../Operation/trialbooking.operation';
import { getclient } from '../Operation/trialbooking.operation';
const Clientlist = () => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [holder, setHolder] = useState([]);

    const readExcel = (file) => {
        const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file[0]);
            fileReader.onload = (e) => {
                console.log("here0", e.target.result); //here i am coverting excel file into json.
                const bufferArray = e.target.result;
                const wb = XLSX.read(bufferArray, { type: "buffer" });
                const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
                const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];  
                const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws);
                resolve(data);
            };
            fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
                reject(error);
            };
        });
        promise.then((d) => {
            let it = items;
            let it1 = it.concat(d)
            setHolder(it1) //after converting holding data in this variable.
        });

    };
    async function getdetail() {// this function is to retrieve data 
        let data = await getclient()
        let user = []
        data.forEach(doc => {
            user.push(doc.data())
        })
        setItems(user)
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        getdetail();

    }, []);
    console.log(items);
    const upload = async () => {
//here iam uploding data to database.
        const object2 = Object.fromEntries(
            Object.entries(holder)
                .map(([key, val]) => [key, val])
        );
        await filedata(object2);
        setItems(holder);

    }
    return (

        <><h1>Clientlist</h1>
            <div className="table">
                <input
                    type="file"
                    className="input-field"
                    accept=".csv, .xlsx,.xls,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel"
                    onChange={(e) => {
                        const file = [...e.target.files];
                        console.log("here", file);
                        // const file1 = e.target.files[1];
                        readExcel(file);
                    }}
                    multiple
                />
                <button onClick={upload}> upload</button>
                <table className="table table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr className="bg-light">
                            <th scope="col" >NO</th>
                            <th scope="col" >SOFTWARE</th>
                            <th scope="col" >SERIES</th>
                            <th scope="col" >STATE</th>
                            <th scope="col" >PARTYNAME</th>
                            <th scope="col" >ADDRESS</th>
                            <th scope="col" >PHONENO</th>
                            <th scope="col" >GMAIL</th>
                            <th scope="col" >USER</th>
                            <th scope="col" >ADDITION</th>
                            <th scope="col" >USERNO</th>
                            <th scope="col" >OWNERNAME</th>
                            <th scope="col" >BUYDATE</th>
                            <th scope="col" >STATUS</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {items.map((d) => ( //here iam trying to get map data
                            (<tr key={d.items}>
                                <td>{d.NO}</td>
                                <td>{d.SOFTWARE}</td>
                                <td>{d.SERIES}</td>
                                <td>{d.STATE}</td>
                                <td>{d.PARTYNAME}</td>
                                <td>{d.ADDRESS}</td>
                                <td>{d.PHONENO}</td>
                                <td>{d.GMAIL}</td>
                                <td>{d.USER}</td>
                                <td>{d.ADDITION}</td>
                                <td>{d.USERNO}</td>
                                <td>{d.OWNERNAME}</td>
                                <td>{d.BUYDATE}</td>
                                <td>{d.STATUS}</td>
                            </tr>)
                        ))}

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </>

    )
}

export default Clientlist;
```

and this my retrieve query:

```
export const getclient = async () => {
    try {
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "Clientdata"))
        return querySnapshot
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", e);

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you see when you log the querySnapshot?

Comment: What is not working here? Are there any errors or so ?

Comment: @Stanjhae it's shows nothing

Comment: @Dharmaraj  i want to just retreive the data from firestore but iam unable to retrieve the data